# How to pass data from HTML to NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js

I currently have an app.js file and an index.html file, I want to pass data from a index.html to app.js.

I am trying to use expressJS to perform a post request but is doesn't seem to be handling the data.

HTML:

```
<form action="./index.html" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

NodeJS:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

On the server command line I am getting /POST so I is registering that a post request is being made but console.log() isn't initialising with the data.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: `action` inside `<form />` should be `/` instead of `/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make a working example and have uploaded it to this repo.

https://github.com/crimson-eagle/nodeJS-POST-FORM